# How to define and call java methods in jmeter using Wedriver Sampler

Tags: java, selenium, methods, jmeter, webdriver

I have a java method of generating random strings.how can i define and call method in jmeter WebDriver sampler so that instead of giving string in `sendkeys()` i can generate string randomly.
My code of WebDriver is :

```
  WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath(".//*
  [@id='chassisNumber']")).sendKeys("ADSDF");
```

In above, i am giving the chassis number manually

My Code of generating random string is:

```
    String chassisNO = createRandomHexValues(6);
    public static String createRandomHexValues(int nValues) {
    String chassis = "";
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < nValues; i++) {

        chassis += CHARACTERS.charAt(random.nextInt(26));
    }
    return chassis;
```

I simply want to generated random chassis number every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript equivalent would be something like:

```
function createRandomHexValues(nValues) {
  var chassis  = "";
  var CHARACTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  for (var i = 0; i < nValues ; i++)
    chassis  += CHARACTERS.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * CHARACTERS.length));

  return chassis ;
}
```

Another option is compiling your Java code into .jar file, adding it to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and calling it as per [Using Java From Scripts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html) guide.

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) article for more WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks if needed

Comment: Clean & precise answer (+1)